# Gunicorn not loading environment file

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn service file that looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=afrinovate-admin
Group=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/etc/afrinovate/gunicorn.env
WorkingDirectory=/home/afrinovate-admin/afrinovate
ExecStart=/home/afrinovate-admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/afrinovate-VhxtDRfD/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          afrinovate.wsgi:application
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when i try starting gunicorn i get this error about not SECRET_KEY empty, which is in the EnvironmentFile specified in the gunicorn file.

```
File "/home/afrinovate-admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/afrinovate-VhxtDRfD/lib/python3.7/site-
May 06 20:54:25 afrinovate-test-api gunicorn[7293]:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("`enter code here`The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

May 06 20:54:25 afrinovate-test-api gunicorn[7293]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: Try the command: `source /etc/afrinovate/gunicorn.env`

Comment: @SuhFangmbeng Tried it, that didn't work either